# I want to implement a function about I/O in Android studio: see if ‘list.txt’ exists then initialize a listview with the strings in the file

Tags: java, android

Requirements:
When the application is executed, it should now check to see if ‘list.txt’ exists. If it does, it should initialize the To Do List with the file contents. If it does not, do not open the stream to list.txt.

And my code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private ArrayList<String> noteList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
    private EditText input;
    private ListView listview;
    String noteText; //text of the note
    private TextToSpeech speaker;

    private int clickedIndex; //starting from 0
    private int indexEndPos;
    private boolean clicked; // initialized to false
    private static final String tag = "Widgets";

    private final String file = "list.txt";

    private OutputStreamWriter out;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputField);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

// open stream for reading
//Read text from file

        BufferedReader inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream =
                    new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String line;
        int i = 0;
        String[] text = new String[20];
        try {
            while ((line = inputStream.readLine())!= null) {
                text[i++] = line;
            }   inputStream.close();                   
            ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(text));
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, text);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(file, MODE_PRIVATE));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e3) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You never asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(<PATH_TO_DIRECTORY>, <FILE_NAME>);    


if (file.exists()) {
    //Open the stream and get file contents
} else {
    //Don't open the stream and do whatever else
}
```

A few extra tidbits:

If your file is stored in external storage, the directory path should be:

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), <FILE_NAME>);
```

^^Permissions are required to read from and write to external storage.

If your file is stored in your App's internal storage:

```
new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), <FILE_NAME>);
```

^^No permissions required, Contents not visible anywhere except your app.

If you're trying to read a file from the assets folder, you can get an InputStream of the file directly from AssetManager, which can be accessed with getAssets():

```
InputStream in = context.getAssets().open("list.txt");
```

Comment: File f = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(),file);
The log said, The file doesn't exist.

Comment: After execution of :  File file = new File(<PATH_TO_DIRECTORY>, <FILE_NAME>);Will (file.exists()) 
always be true? I think it's to create a file, not to detect an existing file?

Comment: Okay when you instantiate a File object:

Comment: (...continued because i missed the edit time limit) in code, it doesn't automatically create a new File in your Files directory. In order to actually create the physical file, you need to call file.createNewFile() (or file.mkDir() if your creating a new directory). This will create a new empty file at that location in your storage (If and only if a file with that name does not yet exist). file.exists() will now return true. So once you instantiate your File object, you can check if it exists, and if it doesn't, create it. if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();.